# How to Implement a button-press-event on GtkTable

Tags: c, gtk

Searching the web for answers dosen't get me through my problem:

I wan't my GtkTable to throw an event, if i click one cell.

Since there is no click event, accept for GtkButton's, i wanted to implement a **GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK** and **GDK_BUTTON_RELEASE_MASK** to catch the position of the mouse on the Table during *click*. 
Works great with GtkDrawingArea!

Tryed the snipet bellow, but nothing happend, maybe someone can give me a clue :)

little sample:

```
static void table_press(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *event)
{
    printf("table pressed");
} 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget* table;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW (window), "table click");

    table = gtk_table_new(2, 5, TRUE);

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), table);

    gtk_widget_add_events(table, GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK);

    g_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT (table), "button-press-event",
        G_CALLBACK (table_press), NULL);
    g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy",
        G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), G_OBJECT(window));

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main();
    main_exit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? GtkTable is a container to hold other widgets, so they would most likely get the signal. If there are no widgets attached, the table size might be (0,0).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't receive events because `GtkTable` does not have a `GdkWindow` associated with it. You can use `GtkEventBox` which lets you accept events on widgets that would not normally accept events. This is derived from `GtkBin` so the interesting code would look like this.

```
table = gtk_table_new(2, 5, TRUE);
event_box = gtk_event_box_new();
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (window), event_box);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (event_box), table);
g_signal_connect(GTK_OBJECT (event_box), "button-press-event",
    G_CALLBACK (table_press), NULL);
```

Comment: Thanks allot! this helped me out.