# How to block a gtk button from being pressed two times?

Tags: c, button, gtk, glade

I have this code, that fills a table with buttons:

```
box1 = gtk_builder_get_object( builder, "box1");

grid = gtk_grid_new();
gtk_grid_set_column_homogeneous(GTK_GRID(grid), TRUE);
gtk_grid_set_row_homogeneous(GTK_GRID(grid), TRUE);

gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box1), grid, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
for (i = 0, fila = 0; i < CANT_BOTONES ; i++)
{
    /* Boton a ser creado */
    //GtkWidget *botontab;

    /* Crear boton con el texto concatenado */
    //botontab = gtk_button_new();
    tabbotones[i].buttontab = gtk_button_new();

    //turn = *ptrturn;
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(tabbotones[i].buttontab), "clicked", G_CALLBACK( juega_gtk ), i);

    /* Calcular columna del grid donde se ubicará el botón */
    columna = i % CANT_COLUMNAS;

    /* Calcular fila del grid donde se ubicará el botón */
    if (i && !columna)
        fila++;

    tabbotones[i].fila = fila;
    tabbotones[i].columna = columna;

    /* Agregar botón al grid */
    gtk_grid_attach(GTK_GRID(grid), GTK_WIDGET(tabbotones[i].buttontab), columna, fila, ANCHURA_BOTON, ALTURA_BOTON);
    printf("%d %d -- %d %d\n", fila, columna, tabbotones[i].fila, tabbotones[i].columna );
}
```

What I want, is that only one time a button can be pressed, not two or more times. I dont know how to block this. The only thing I came out searching on the internet is this: 
[How to Implement a button-press-event on GtkTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414613/how-to-implement-a-button-press-event-on-gtktable)
but how I save the information of the gtkbutton that was pressed already?, I think the only way is to save that info in my struct that has the buttons and its coordinates on it, but how?. Thanks in advance!.

Comment: Are they hardware or software buttons?

Comment: `g_signal_connect` returns a `handle_id` which can be used to [disconnect](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-handler-disconnect) or [block](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-handler-block) the signal handler.If you can access the `handle_id` in callback you can block or disconnect it

Comment: Software buttons only.

Comment: How I access the handle_id?

Answer (score 2):

You can attach arbitrary values to any `GObject` (thereby to any `GtkWidget`) with [`g_object_set_data`](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html#g-object-set-data).

If I understood your question, you can leverage this feature to accomplish what you need:

```
/* In the loop */
g_object_set_data(button, "clicks", GINT_TO_POINTER(0));


/* In the callback */
gint clicks = GPOINTER_TO_INT(g_object_get_data(button, "clicks") + 1;
g_object_set_data(button, "clicks", GINT_TO_POINTER(clicks));

if (clicks == 1) {
    /* Handle your first click */
}
```

`GPOINTER_TO_INT` and `GINT_TO_POINTER` are just C conveniences to avoid the use of dynamic memory.

Comment: For example, I place a token for the reversi game, then, in that button where the token was placed, you should not be able to click again.

Comment: @juan: what do you mean? Is that a question?

Comment: It is not, is a clarification only.