# How can I have a GTKLabel which changes based on mouse position?

Tags: c++, gtk, label, mouseevent, gtk2

I've read the documentation but can't find anything for this.
For example, if I have a table and mouse over the top left, it'll say (0, 0), and it'll change accordingly based on where I mouse next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your purpose is and probably there are better ways to achieve your final goal but anyway,

You must connect a signal to the widget you want the mouse to be tracked at. The signal is from GtkWidget and it's called [**motion-notify-event**](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/2.24/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#a46e819f54ebc992b9abb4edef6dcb4b1). The signal handler will receive the event with mice x and y coordinates.

If you want to track the mouse when it's over the GtkTable (which inherits from GtkWidget) then just connect the signal to it and have the callback update the GtkLabel.

**EDIT:**

As @jku stated, some widgets don't receive these events because they don't have a GdkWindow. Probably the best option would be to add the table to a EventBox container and then proceed as stated previously. Also, this question has been made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414613/how-to-implement-a-button-press-event-on-gtktable).

Comment: The last paragraph is a bit misleading: I'm pretty sure Motion-notify-event still only works for widgets which have a GdkWindow, and GtkTable does not have one. Also the GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK mask needs to be set on the widget.

Comment: @jku there are some nuances. I'll edit the message later, im on mobile and aint so easy. Could be a eventbox container  or just enable the motion mask flags... The idea was to point him on the right direction. Tks for feedback